# PHP MySQL query shows the current date of the table by date before 1 month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, date

I will create a notification system with 1 month notice before deadline.
I have a problem displaying a date that coincides with the current date.
I want to show that appears only date today from the deadline date  before 1 month deadline.

My tabel = notif :

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | name       | deadline   |
+------+------------+------------+
| 01   | Daniel     | 2018-02-13 |
| 02   | Elwin      | 2018-02-12 |
| 03   | Dika       | 2018-02-13 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

For example : date today = 2018-01-13 
report table what i want :

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+
| id   | name       | deadline   | alert_now  |
+------+------------+------------+------------+
| 01   | Daniel     | 2018-02-13 | 2018-01-13 |
| 03   | Dika       | 2018-02-13 | 2018-01-13 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+
```

My Query in model of codeigniter :

```
public function notification(){
        $query=$this->db->query('SELECT *, DATE_SUB(deadline, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as alert_now FROM notif WHERE now() = DATE_SUB(deadline, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');
        return $result=$query;
    }
```

Note : Sorry, my english is poor. Thank you.

Comment: I guess `deadline` `2018-01-13` for `Dika` is wrong in your expected result ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean | 03   | Dika       | 2018-02-13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you deadline is date type 
Instead of now() (date time )  you should use curdate()  (date)

```
  public function notification(){
          $query=$this->db->query('SELECT *, DATE_SUB(deadline, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as alert_now 
                    FROM notif WHERE curdate() = DATE_SUB(deadline, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');
          return $result=$query;
      }
```

if deadline is datetime then you should get the date parte  eg:

```
  date(DATE_SUB(deadline, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```